# Ffmpeg c++ can't compile with libxh264

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, compilation, linker, libx264

I made a program that uses the source version of ffmpeg. I get the code from it's website and compile/configured it. The problem is I want to configure it with the libx264 flag so it looks like this:

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl
```

Ffmpeg itself compiles with no errors, however when I try to compile my own code using `make` I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/Application.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/opengl/OpenGLRenderer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/opengl/texture.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/opengl/text_render.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/opengl/image_render.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/logging/Log.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/utils/color_converter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/utils/maths.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/utils/sys_util.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/types/segment.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/types/timeline.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/coms/json_parser.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/coms/socket.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/video_io/video_encoder.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/video_io/video_decode.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/src/video_io/audio_mixer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Renderer.dir/lib/glad/src/glad.c.o -o bin/Renderer  /usr/local/lib/libavformat.a /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a /usr/local/lib/libswresample.a /usr/local/lib/libswscale.a /usr/local/lib/libavutil.a /usr/local/lib/libavdevice.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so lib/glfw/src/libglfw3.a lib/spdlog/libspdlog.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.a -lm -ldl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in function `X264_frame':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:349: undefined reference to `x264_picture_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:518: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_encode'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:551: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_delayed_frames'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in function `reconfig_encoder':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:297: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:212: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:224: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:250: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:217: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o):/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:230: more undefined references to `x264_encoder_reconfig' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in function `X264_close':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:605: undefined reference to `x264_param_cleanup'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:609: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_close'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in function `parse_opts':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:621: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): in function `X264_init':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:699: undefined reference to `x264_param_default'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:704: undefined reference to `x264_param_default_preset'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:729: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:763: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:795: undefined reference to `x264_levels'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:820: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:821: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:822: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:823: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:883: undefined reference to `x264_param_apply_fastfirstpass'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:924: undefined reference to `x264_param_apply_profile'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:1012: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'From the updated error it appears you're explicitly linking with /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a etc. So the problem almost certainly lies with your CMakeLists.txt file(s). – 

/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:1032: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_163'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:1041: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_headers'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:1072: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_maximum_delayed_frames'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode_h264.o): in function `vaapi_encode_h264_configure':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode_h264.c:1096: undefined reference to `vaQueryVendorString'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode_h265.o): in function `vaapi_encode_h265_get_encoder_caps':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode_h265.c:1176: undefined reference to `vaGetConfigAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode_h265.c:1190: undefined reference to `vaGetConfigAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_wait':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:157: undefined reference to `vaSyncBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:168: undefined reference to `vaSyncSurface'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:170: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:161: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_free_output_buffer':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2412: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_make_packed_header':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:60: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:71: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:64: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:75: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_make_param_buffer':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:101: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:104: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_alloc_output_buffer':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2430: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2435: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2447: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_issue':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:637: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:583: undefined reference to `vaBeginPicture'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:592: undefined reference to `vaRenderPicture'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:601: undefined reference to `vaEndPicture'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:618: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:621: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:595: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:634: undefined reference to `vaEndPicture'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:586: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:603: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_output':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:668: undefined reference to `vaMapBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:699: undefined reference to `vaUnmapBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:701: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:671: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:715: undefined reference to `vaUnmapBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_profile_entrypoint':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1381: undefined reference to `vaMaxNumProfiles'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1387: undefined reference to `vaQueryConfigProfiles'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1389: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1411: undefined reference to `vaProfileStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1441: undefined reference to `vaMaxNumEntrypoints'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1447: undefined reference to `vaQueryConfigEntrypoints'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1450: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1474: undefined reference to `vaEntrypointStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1499: undefined reference to `vaGetConfigAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1503: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_init_rate_control':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1574: undefined reference to `vaGetConfigAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1578: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_init_gop_structure':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1953: undefined reference to `vaGetConfigAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1958: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1977: undefined reference to `vaGetConfigAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1982: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_init_slice_structure':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2206: undefined reference to `vaGetConfigAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2211: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_init_packed_headers':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2269: undefined reference to `vaGetConfigAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2274: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_init_roi':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2377: undefined reference to `vaGetConfigAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2382: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_init_quality':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2331: undefined reference to `vaGetConfigAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2336: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `vaapi_encode_init_max_frame_size':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1902: undefined reference to `vaGetConfigAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:1908: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `ff_vaapi_encode_init':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2630: undefined reference to `vaCreateConfig'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2635: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2646: undefined reference to `vaCreateContext'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2653: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2727: undefined reference to `vaSyncBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_encode.o): in function `ff_vaapi_encode_close':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2762: undefined reference to `vaDestroyContext'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_encode.c:2767: undefined reference to `vaDestroyConfig'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_decode.o): in function `ff_vaapi_decode_destroy_buffers':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:133: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:143: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:146: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:136: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_decode.o): in function `vaapi_decode_make_config':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:468: undefined reference to `vaMaxNumProfiles'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:476: undefined reference to `vaQueryConfigProfiles'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:540: undefined reference to `vaCreateConfig'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_decode.o): in function `vaapi_decode_find_best_format':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:310: undefined reference to `vaQuerySurfaceAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:322: undefined reference to `vaQuerySurfaceAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_decode.o): in function `vaapi_decode_make_config':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:624: undefined reference to `vaDestroyConfig'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:479: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:544: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_decode.o): in function `vaapi_decode_find_best_format':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:325: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:313: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_decode.o): in function `ff_vaapi_decode_make_param_buffer':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:44: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:47: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_decode.o): in function `ff_vaapi_decode_make_slice_buffer':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:90: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:104: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:95: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:109: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:112: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_decode.o): in function `ff_vaapi_decode_issue':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:163: undefined reference to `vaBeginPicture'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:172: undefined reference to `vaRenderPicture'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:181: undefined reference to `vaRenderPicture'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:190: undefined reference to `vaEndPicture'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:192: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:166: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:210: undefined reference to `vaEndPicture'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:212: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:175: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:184: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_decode.o): in function `ff_vaapi_common_frame_params':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:650: undefined reference to `vaDestroyConfig'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi_decode.o): in function `ff_vaapi_decode_uninit':
/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:707: undefined reference to `vaDestroyContext'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:709: undefined reference to `vaErrorStr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/vaapi_decode.c:715: undefined reference to `vaDestroyConfig'
```

(The error is a bit longer but I think this is ample for now.)

The thing is, this code also runs on the cloud and compiles just fine without the `--enable-libx264` flags. And inside the cloud, it works just fine even with the libx264 flag. But when I follow the exact same steps as the cloud and try to compile it locally, it gives this error.

Here are the steps I have followed:

First I removed ffmpeg (It was a bit messy) using  `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove ffmpeg` then I made sure its deleted by searching `find / -name ffmpeg` and manually deleting my findings. Then, I ran `apt-get install -y libx264-dev`, followed by `./configure --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl`  inside the directory where I have downloaded the source files. Then ran `make` and `make install` where ffmpeg source files are. I ran `ldconfig` so it can detect shared libs (This is how it works on the cloud) and finally ran `make` on my own codes directory and got the error mentioned.

Here is my CMakeFile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(Renderer C CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

SET( EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${dir}/bin )
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin )


add_definitions(-DGL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION)
add_definitions("-g -lglad -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lvdpau -lz -lva -lavformat -lavcodec- -lswscale -lavutil -lavfiter -lswresample 
-lavdevice -lpostproc  -loa -lz -lx264 -llzma -lbz2 -lrt -lx264 -pthread -lm  -lva-drm -lva-x11")

list(APPEND SOURCES
    ...
)

find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

find_path(AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR libavformat/avformat.h)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat)

find_path(AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR libavdevice/avdevice.h)
find_library(AVDEVICE_LIBRARY avdevice)

find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

find_path(AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR libavutil/avutil.h)
find_library(AVUTIL_LIBRARY avutil)

find_path(SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIR libswresample/swresample.h)
find_library(SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARY swresample)

find_path(SWSCALE_INCLUDE_DIR libswscale/swscale.h)
find_library(SWSCALE_LIBRARY swscale)

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)

add_executable(Renderer src/main.cpp src/Application.cpp src/Application.h ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(Renderer PRIVATE Threads::Threads)

list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
    "-lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lz -lva -lswresample -lx264 -shared -lvdpau -lva  -lm  -lva-drm -lva-x11"
)

target_include_directories(Renderer PRIVATE 
    ${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR} 
    ${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR} 
    ${SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${SWSCALE_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR} 
)

target_link_libraries(Renderer PRIVATE 
    ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY} 
    ${AVCODEC_LIBRARY} 
    ${SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARY}
    ${SWSCALE_LIBRARY}
    ${AVUTIL_LIBRARY} 
    ${AVDEVICE_LIBRARY} 
)
```

Like I said, it works on the cloud just the way it is and everything works without the `--enable-libx264` flag.

How can I fix this? I'm on ubuntu 22+

Comment: You configured `ffmpeg` with `--enable-shared` but you're linking against `libavcodec.a` -- that's not right.  Where did your build of `ffmpeg` install the various `libav*.so` etc. shared objects?

Comment: @G.M. I ran `sudo find / -name libavcodec.so` and found there are two result, one is where I uploaded ffmepg's source codes and where I compiled it (/home/turgut/Desktop/CppProjects/videoo-render/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec as seen in the error) and one is localted at `/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so`

Comment: Firstly, please edit your question to show the error messages as formatted text rather than an image (can't be searched).  Also, please provide the link command that generates the error.  If it's selecting the static rather than shared libraries then I suspect you're using `-Wl,-static` or similar.

Comment: @G.M. I'm sorry I did not account for the fact that people can search it. I've updated the question accordingly. However I was force to cut the few lines at the end since it exceeded stackoverflow's max letter limit. I can't provide my link command either since it's a big CMake file.

Comment: You can use `make VERBOSE=1` to see the commands as they are executed.

Comment: @G.M. Updated the question with the verbose output.

Comment: From the updated error it appears you're explicitly linking with `/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a` etc.    So the problem almost certainly lies with your `CMakeLists.txt` file(s).

Comment: How do we link implicitly to the shared version of the libavcodec.so library then ?

Comment: This is currently what we use : 
find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

find_path(AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR libavformat/avformat.h)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat)

find_path(AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR libavdevice/avdevice.h)
find_library(AVDEVICE_LIBRARY avdevice)

find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

find_path(AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR libavutil/avutil.h)
find_library(AVUTIL_LIBRARY avutil)

Comment: @G.M. I've updated the question and cut some parts of the error message so I can include the CMakeLists file since you have already seen the error message and there is a maximum letter limit.